# Clipboard doesn't work when I load my main executable assembly manually

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have a C# project that I am running it from a VC++ project. I've used `Clipboard` in my C# project; but when I'm running my C# project from VC++ it doesn't work properly.

My C# code:

```
IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (dataObject.GetDataPresent("MyType",true))     //This returns true in both of cases
  Console.WriteLine("Here");
object obj = dataObject.GetData("MyType");    //obj is null
MyType data = obj as MyType;
// When I copy data from normal program to called program (from VC++) this is null
```

Apparently I can not use `Clipboard` in the projects that are not `STAThread`. The entry point of my C# project is `STAThread` but I don't know how can I make my VC++ project `STAThread`?

Edit: `Application.OleRequired() == ApartmentState.STA` returns `true` and My thread was `STAThread`.

Comment: Why and how are you calling C# from C++ that it does not invoke a new process? Can you post some code?

Comment: @nvoigt I'm using this method to run my C# projec: [Igor Ladnik](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674455/Anti-Reflector-NET-Code-Protection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this project I'm doing somethings manually,for example :

- Loading my main executable assembly manually by `Assembly.Load()`.
- Assembly resolving by handling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e)` event.

After loading the main assembly it request for itself to get `Assembly` object. In this case after loading main executable assembly you should store the `Assembly` object and return it in `AssemblyResolve` method.

That was my problem, unbelievable!

Answer (score 0):

Just add above your main `[System::STAThread]`

Comment: My C# project is STAThread; but my problem is about my VC++ project.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh The solution S.Spieker proposed is to add the attribute to your C++ application.

Comment: @UweKeim Should I add 'using namespace System;' to my code?

Comment: @S.Spieker I cannot compile my code: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh have you added a reference to WindowsBase?

Comment: @S.Spieker I know C++ but I'm not expert in VC++ and I've copied this code from the internet. It is so complicated for me. How should I do that?

Comment: @S.Spieker But in "Add Reference" window I just can see the other projects of my Solution.